# Configuring cygwin sshd-host-config through script on REMOTE Windows hosts

Tags: cygwin, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to Install CYGWIN on Win2016 and 2012 server and configure sshd-host-config for for an agent server to push agent to the target windows VMs. I some how googled and managed to get PS code to install CYGWIN 64 bit version but i'm looking to automate the configuration of sshd-host-config(this is an interactive and asks for multiple yes/no input and a text) and net-start-sshd after configuration. Could any one help on this please? Thanks in advance.

Here is the piece of code for installing CYGWIN: (i got this code by googling and not my own piece)

````
$exeFilePath = "C:\cygwin64\setup-x86_64.exe"
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe', $exeFilePath)
Start-Process "C:\cygwin64\setup-x86_64.exe" -ArgumentList "--quiet-mode --root C:\cygwin64 --site http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com --packages `"curl,python,python-crypto,openssl,openssh,zip,unzip`"" -Wait -NoNewWindow;
Write-Host "Installed Cygwin x64" -ForegroundColor Green ```
````